# Minus sign on the left and comma as separation sign

Tags: types, abap, display, alv

I want to display a decimal number on an ALV. But the minus sign on negative values is shown on the right side. When I use the FA "CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT" I need to use a char typed value. If I do that the comma is replaced by a separation point.

How can I achieve both, minus sign on the left and comma as separation sign.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Which ALV are you using?

Comment: I'm using SALV. But without a fieldcatalog.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CL_SALV_COLUMN` method `SET_EDIT_MASK` to set either a classic mask or a conversion exit. For some reason, that method was lost in the translation of the online documentation - it is present in the [German version](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_dm40/helpdata/de/64/e7eb40c4f8712ae10000000a155106/content.htm?frameset=/de/ec/e7eb40c4f8712ae10000000a155106/frameset.htm&current_toc=/de/66/88d440e14f8431e10000000a1550b0/plain.htm&node_id=35), but missing in the [English version](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_dm40/helpdata/en/64/e7eb40c4f8712ae10000000a155106/content.htm?frameset=/de/ec/e7eb40c4f8712ae10000000a155106/frameset.htm&current_toc=/de/66/88d440e14f8431e10000000a1550b0/plain.htm&node_id=35).

Comment: I tried it with mask `'-___,__'`. But when the value is 0 it will be displayed like. `-00 ,`

Comment: You may want to [refresh your knowledge about edit masks](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abapwrite_to_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_13@13@) - especially, use `V` for the sign and `.` for the decimal separator.